# prove that $3(a+b+c) \geq 8(a b c)^{1 / 3}+\left(\frac{a^{3}+b^{3}+c^{3}}{3}\right)^{1 / 3}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, contest-math, holder-inequality, uvw

**Question** -

Suppose a,b,c are positive real numbers , prove that

$3(a+b+c) \geq 8(a b c)^{1 / 3}+\left(\frac{a^{3}+b^{3}+c^{3}}{3}\right)^{1 / 3}$

(Thailand $2006$)

**My attempt** -

we can assume that $a+b+c=1$ so we have to prove that

$3 \geq 8(a b c)^{1 / 3}+\left(\frac{a^{3}+b^{3}+c^{3}}{3}\right)^{1 / 3}$
but i am not able to show that it is true..

then i tried some AM-GM on RHS but none of them work,
i think this is most different inequalities i have came across so i did not know where to go .

any help will be appreciated

thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, we can use the following Holder:
$$3(a+b+c)\geq\sqrt[3]{9^2(8abc+\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{3}})\geq8\sqrt[3]{abc}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{3}},$$
where the first inequality it's just Muirhead or AM-GM.

Answer (score 4):

Let $a+n+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$ and $abc=w^3$.

Thus, we need to prove that $f(w^3)\leq0,$ where $$f(w^3)=8w+\sqrt{9u^3-9uv^2+w^3}-9u.$$
But, we see that $f$ increases, which says that it's enough to prove our inequality for a maximal value of $w^3$, which happens for equality case of two variables.

Since, our inequality is homogeneous, we can assume that $b=c=1$

because the case $b=c=0$ is trivial.

Can you end it now?

Comment: thanks ,but is there a proof using classic inequalities ???

Comment: @Ishan Yes, of course! But, I think the solution by $uvw$ is the best here. I am ready to try if you want.

Comment: the problem is that i am not very much familiar with $uvw$ so if is there a proof that is NICER then $uvw$ then pls provide it , thanks

Comment: @Ishan About $uvw$ you can read here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h278791

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to assume a+b+c=1, you can prove this for genral case by applying am,gm inequality on a,b,c and a^3,b^3,c^3.[image: sorry for the image quality, i hope it's readable]

Comment: Sorry for the image quality

Comment: This doesn't work, you cannot subtract inequalities like that.

Comment: Why not, i think you can

Comment: If it worked like that, then $x \ge y$ and $z \ge y$ would imply $x = z$ by subtracting the inequalities from each other and comparing.

Comment: @Atharv no, you can't ... $2>1$ and $3>1$, if you subtract $-1>0$.

Comment: Alright , i get it now, it didn't look like a wrong step at first look,but it is